# How to replace 0s in a matrix with a pre-specified value

Tags: r, matrix

```
mat <- diag(3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

I have a matrix with 1 along the diagonal and 0 everywhere else. I want to replace the 0s with 0.3, so the matrix looks like

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  0.3  0.3
[2,]  0.3    1  0.3
[3,]  0.3  0.3    1
```

What's a quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could create a boolean vector that indicates the `0` and assign it each element which is `TRUE`

```
mat[mat == 0] <- 0.3
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.3  0.3
[2,]  0.3  1.0  0.3
[3,]  0.3  0.3  1.0
```

G.Grothendieck2 is in front in terms of speed :-)
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try this sum

```
mat + 0.3 * (1 - mat)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  1.0  0.3  0.3
## [2,]  0.3  1.0  0.3
## [3,]  0.3  0.3  1.0
```

A variation of that is to write it as the following convex combination of mat and 1.

```
0.7 * mat + 0.3
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  1.0  0.3  0.3
## [2,]  0.3  1.0  0.3
## [3,]  0.3  0.3  1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `replace`

```
replace(mat, !mat, 0.3)
```

Or may also do

```
(!mat) * 0.3 + mat
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.3  0.3
[2,]  0.3  1.0  0.3
[3,]  0.3  0.3  1.0
```